# Angular "No action was found on the controller 'Usuario' that matches the request."

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

Im working with asp.net web api with angular so I´m making recovery password, I have the following steps:

1. User Click on recovery password
2. He enters hes username and received email with recovery url (with specific token) like:

   http://localhost:55720/Cliente/#/cambiarContrasena.html?Token=f0faa24e-a543-4806-820c-d0c31c69b180

And I see View without problems but when I try to post new credentials I received

> "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:55718/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena'."
>       "No action was found on the controller 'Usuario' that matches the request."

**Angular Controller:**

```
(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('cambiarContrasenaCtrl', cambiarContrasenaCtrl);

    cambiarContrasenaCtrl.$inject =['$scope', 'notificationService', '$rootScope', 'vcRecaptchaService', 'membershipService', '$state', 'apiService', '$window'];

    function cambiarContrasenaCtrl($scope, notificationService, $rootScope, vcRecaptchaService, membershipService, $state, apiService, $window) {


        $scope.usuario = {};
        $scope.cambiarContrasena = cambiarContrasena;

        function cambiarContrasena() {
            $('#recovery').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.page-spinner-bar').removeClass('hide');
            membershipService.cambiarContrasena($scope.usuario, credencialCorrecta, credencialIncorrecta);
        }

        function credencialCorrecta(response) {
            $('#recovery').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.page-spinner-bar').addClass('hide');
            notificationService.mostrarExito(response.data.mostrarExito);
            //redigir a estado, dashboard o previo en caso de existir
        }

        function credencialIncorrecta(response) {

            notificationService.mostrarError(response.data.errores);
            $('#recovery').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.page-spinner-bar').addClass('hide');
        }


    }

})(angular.module('common.core'));
```

after pass:  `membershipService.cambiarContrasena($scope.usuario, credencialCorrecta, credencialIncorrecta);` it throws error message

**app.js:**

```
.state('cambiarContrasena', {
                 url: "/cambiarContrasena.html",
                 templateUrl: "../SPA/cuenta/cambiarContrasena.html",
                 controller: "cambiarContrasenaCtrl",
                 authenticate: false,
                 data: { pageTitle: 'CAMBIAR CONTRASEÑA' },
                 resolve: {
                     deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                         return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                             name: 'portalTransporte',
                             insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files
                             files: [
                                 "/Metronic/pages/css/login-5.css",
                                 "/Metronic/custom/login.css"
                             ]
                         });
                     }]
                 }
             })
```

**membershipService.js**

```
 function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
        apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena', usuario,
        completado,
        fallo);
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace PortalDeTransporte.Web.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/usuario")]
    public class UsuarioController : ApiControllerBase
    {
  [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("cambiarContrasena")]
        public HttpResponseMessage cambiarContrasena(HttpRequestMessage request, string token)
        {

            return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _usuarioRecuperacionService.CambiarContrasena(token);
                }
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

someone looking anything wrong? Help is very appreciated. Regards

Comment: this is your asp.net service issue. are you using WEB API?

Comment: Yes I´m using WEB API @Aravind

Comment: look at the controller and the matching request. if need help are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: Yes I have team viewer but I dont have microphone @Aravind

Comment: You're passing 3 parameters to your API method, but it only accepts 2.

Comment: where do you see want parameters I accept? @Lex

Comment: `public HttpResponseMessage cambiarContrasena(HttpRequestMessage request, string token)`